# Does appengine have a new limitation on "Exceeded maximum allocated IDs"?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My app is running fine for months. Today it starts to give error on "Exceeded maximum allocated IDs" with datastore put. Is this something new with appengine quota and limitation?

http://gochild2009.appspot.com

Comment: Are you doing something like calling `allocate_ids()` or `allocate_id_range()` with large numbers?

Comment: No, just datastore.put(entity).

Comment: I'm getting close to find the problem. The kind which gives "Exceeded maximum allocated IDs" only has 1483 entities, but the last entity id=9223259787550119662. This is almost 2^63, which is the limit. I have been using this kind since 2010, it seems the ID generator might be root cause of this error.

Comment: I found another kind which gives "Exceeded maximum allocated IDs". This kind only has 2545 entities. Looking at the id sequence, at around 1223 entity id=6070550, the next entity id=9223259787545785651 and increasing. The id generator is behaving strangely.

Comment: I have a kind which shows the time of id jump as shown below.
id=6045690,             2011-11-17 03:24:34.576000
id=9223259787545788651, 2011-11-18 16:09:36.499000

Comment: Another kind shows the id jump at about the same time.
id=6071550,             2011-11-18 06:00:31.469000
id=9223259787545787652, 2011-11-18 15:51:32.743000

Comment: Kinds in my app with key generated by myself still function well. Kinds which I let datastore generate key automatically all has "Exceeded maximum allocated IDs" problem now.

Comment: This definitely looks like a bug - it shouldn't be possible for the sequence to jump that suddenly. You should definitely report it.

Comment: It is GAE issue 9110, but somehow it is Restricted, Only users with Commit permission can see this issue.

Answer (score 0):

While we're unsure how you ended up with such large ids, we are taking steps to accommodate them.

You can track this on https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9118.

Thanks.

Comment: It is GAE issue 9110. Somehow it becomes restricted, only users with Commit permission can see this issue.

Comment: The time of id large jump is interesting. 2011/11 was when GAE exited beta.

Comment: Instead of letting datastore to generate id automatically, I am now generating id for most of my kinds. Luckily several important kinds do not rely on automatic id generation. My app is back online. Is my app the only one experiencing this scary issue?

Comment: Your link to issue 9118 is also not accessible. I can't track it.

Comment: I opened the issue 9118. I have the same exception on another app in appengine. I think that you cannot see because it is a production issue.

Comment: In my case the large numbers started when I migrated from Master Slave to HRD (I thought it was normal). I know because I had to change the code to pass IDs as Strings at that point.

Comment: Hi, gosharplite, Sorry 9118 was not visible. Could you follow this now on https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9145 . That one should be visible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Our app had the same problem.

There is not such a limit (quota). It seems that at some point the ID generate for some entities is to high and this exception is thrown.

As a solution/workaround you can generate your own IDs.

Comment: The issue 9118 is still in accepted status. We created a new version which generates its own IDs because we could not wait for the issue to be fixed.