# "Exceeded maximum allocated IDs"-Exception when allocating KeyRange (AppEngine Objectify)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I am migrating some entities from an old appengine application to a new one (one reason beside others is to upgrade to objectify 5).

There are also some entities that have a automatically generated long id. Now I have to re-[allocate the ids](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Kinds_and_identifiers) (see also the [javadoc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#allocateIdRange-com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyRange-) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/objectify-appengine/id$20range/objectify-appengine/IgFAzxhRADk/mBY5784VoZEJ) discussion) on the new datastore.

This are the important lines:

```
Long id = anEntity.getId();
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyRange keyRange = new com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyRange(null, AnEntity.class.getName(), id-1l, id+1l);

KeyRange<AnEntity> keys = new KeyRange<>(keyRange);

OfyService.ofy().factory().allocateIdRange(keys);
```

However, this does not work as the exception below is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exceeded maximum allocated IDs
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:54)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$1.convertException(DatastoreApiHelper.java:127)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:96)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:88)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:36)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.allocateIdRange(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:121)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory.allocateIdRange(ObjectifyFactory.java:335)
```

I tested it further an found that the line

```
KeyRange(null, AnEntity.class.getName(), 1, 1000000000l);
```

would work. However, my already generated ids are in the range of 4503908059709440 to 6754883239673856 which is thus too high, obviously.

1. Did I made some mistake or does the allocateIdRange-method not support such big ids (As hinted [here a long ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800319/does-appengine-have-a-new-limitation-on-exceeded-maximum-allocated-ids))?
2. If the latter, how could I go around this problem?
   (I thought of generating new ids in a certain range, but [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Auto_ID_policy) they say that the legacy-way will soon be removed... Besides I don't like the idea of generating it by myself.)

System:
- Java 7 
- AppengineSDK 1.9.21
- objectify version: 4.1.3 (as said, I am migrating)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the code so that it assigns a String and generate This String with UUID.
This solves the problem but still it is a strange behavior of allocateIdRange...

See also this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11541).